# CouchDB error when running a query in composer-rest-server?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

**Problem:**

I have built a business network and have been deployed and connected through composer-rest-sever. Adding assets and doing transaction functions are working as expected. But when I try to run a query in there it is giving me an error like this.

```
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "name": "Error",
    "message": "transaction returned with failure: Error: GET_QUERY_RESULT failed: transaction ID: e21f7d122609b883f415d82786a197a192b90b344e1e30c304da6c21c838c8bb: Couch DB Error:no_usable_index,  Status Code:400,  Reason:No index exists for this sort, try indexing by the sort fields.",
    "stack": "Error: transaction returned with failure: Error: GET_QUERY_RESULT failed: transaction ID: e21f7d122609b883f415d82786a197a192b90b344e1e30c304da6c21c838c8bb: Couch DB Error:no_usable_index,  Status Code:400,  Reason:No index exists for this sort, try indexing by the sort fields.\n    at C:\\Users\\tharindusa\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\composer-rest-server\\node_modules\\fabric-client\\lib\\Peer.js:114:16\n    at C:\\Users\\tharindusa\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\composer-rest-server\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\client.js:586:7"
  }
}
```

This is how my queries.qry file looks like.

```
query ListLandTitlesForSale{
    description: "List all land titles that are for sale"
   statement:
    SELECT org.landreg.LandTitle
    WHERE (forSale == true)
    ORDER BY [id ASC]
}

query ListLandTitlesBySize {
    description: "List all land titles in a certain size range"
  statement:
    SELECT org.landreg.LandTitle
    WHERE((area >_$minimumArea) AND (area< _$maximumArea))
    ORDER BY [area ASC]
}

query ListOwnedLandTitles {
    description: "List land titles owned by specified 'owner'"
    statement:
        SELECT org.landreg.LandTitle
      WHERE (owner == _$owner)
      ORDER BY [id ASC]
}

query ListPreviouslyOwnedLandTitles {
    description: "List land titles owned by specified 'previousOwner'"
    statement:
        SELECT org.landreg.LandTitle
      WHERE (previousOwners CONTAINS _$previousOwner)
      ORDER BY [id ASC]
}
```

And this is how my .cto file looks.

```
namespace org.landreg

abstract concept Address {
  o String addressLine
  o String locality
}

concept DutchAddress extends Address {
  o String postalCode regex=/\d{4}[ ]?[A-Z]{2}/
}

enum Gender {
  o FEMALE
  o MALE
}

participant Individual identified by passportNumber {
  o String passportNumber
  o DutchAddress address
  o Gender gender
}

asset LandTitle identified by id {
  o String id
  o DutchAddress address
  o Integer area range=[1000,]
  o Boolean forSale default=false
  o Double price optional
  --> Individual owner
  --> Individual[] previousOwners optional
}

transaction UnlockLandTitle {
  --> LandTitle landTitle
}

transaction TransferLandTitle {
  --> LandTitle landTitle
  --> Individual newOwner
}
```

Output of docker ps command

```
TharinduSA@LP-HQ-15957 MINGW64 ~
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                                                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS                                            NAMES
373a6fbe104d        dev-peer0.org1.example.com-landreg-0.0.2-d2a95608b3ed19873963889cfc0dc8c12a2ff883775b0c1263b1f676cab351d5   "/bin/sh -c 'cd /usr…"   5 hours ago         Up 5 hours                                                                 dev-peer0.org1.example.com-landreg-0.0.2
00a0859aaee6        hyperledger/fabric-peer:1.2.0                                                                               "peer node start"        5 hours ago         Up 5 hours                0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0.org1.example.com
83247feca61f        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:1.2.0                                                                            "orderer"                5 hours ago         Up 5 hours                0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer.example.com
a388dc58ac56        hyperledger/fabric-ca:1.2.0                                                                                 "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   5 hours ago         Up 5 hours                0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                           ca.org1.example.com
4ba58264053d        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:0.4.10                                                                           "tini -- /docker-ent…"   5 hours ago         Up 5 hours                4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp       couchdb
5777ea4f350c        dev-peer0.org1.example.com-landreg-0.0.1-9515860cfe680a544a37838162e871043219ac02a5fd224ade345b1aa36d0051   "/bin/sh -c 'cd /usr…"   28 hours ago        Exited (0) 25 hours ago                                                    dev-peer0.org1.example.com-landreg-0.0.1
276df87ca139        dev-peer0.org1.example.com-landreg-0.0.3-2b5a4891dc9504a6280a81420f24ce56b450739cbdfd1d325214910967444f82   "/bin/sh -c 'cd /usr…"   30 hours ago        Exited (0) 29 hours ago                                                    dev-peer0.org1.example.com-landreg-0.0.3
52a0fd951af6        dev-peer0.org1.example.com-sample-0.0.1-3c933e68ad6460ca423125a9eb2529a68675271a61b9f8b3c6a8cd2e722e893c    "/bin/sh -c 'cd /usr…"   31 hours ago        Exited (0) 29 hours ago                                                    dev-peer0.org1.example.com-sample-0.0.1
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem? I am using composer version 0.20.2.

Comment: hi, what version of Fabric? Can you post the output of `docker ps -a` ? Also, are you running on Windows (if so, its officially not supported -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs)

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony Hi!!. I edited the question with `docker ps -a`. Only the queries are not working. adding participant and assets and retriving the adnd updating all these are working as expected.

Comment: hlfv12 is the fabric version

Comment: Right - but are you running your REST server on the Windows host, and your Fabric environment / business network docker containers inside a Linux VM? Can you explain your setup? The problem is the CouchDB indexes were not generated and normally they are auto-generated from the query definitions and you can check http://localhost:5984/_utils/#database/composerchannel/_index  (where composerchannel the channel name, check your name). Also, you'll really need Fabric 1.2.1 too (see [comment here](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/4376#issuecomment-424673147) and not Fabric 1.2.0